# How to parse this xml using simple xml

Tags: android, xml-parsing

```
<folder
    id="-1"
    name="BaseFolder" >
    <folder
        id="1047"
        name="Folder1" >
        <folder
            id="1050"
            name="Folder1.1" />
    </folder>
    <folder
        id="1048"
        name="Folder2" >
        <folder
            id="1053"
            name="Folder2.1" />
        <folder
            id="1054"
            name="Folder2.2" />
    </folder>
    <folder
        id="1049"
        name="Folder3" >
        <folder
            id="1051"
            name="Folder3.1" />
        <folder
            id="1052"
            name="Folder3.2" />
    </folder>
</folder>
```

These are the classes im using

```
    @Root
public class Response extends BaseResponse {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;



    @ElementList(entry="folder", inline=true)
    public ArrayList<Folder> folderList;


    public String getSuccess() {
        return success;
    }

    public void setSuccess(String success) {
        this.success = success;
    }

    @Attribute
    private String success;

    }
```

Folder class

```
@Root
public class Folder extends BaseResponse {




    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Attribute
    private String id;

    @Attribute
    private String name;



    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }



}
```

How can i access the inner folder tags?
In the activity im calling

```
List <Folder>folders=new ArrayList<Folder>();
    Response response = new Response();
response = directoryService.getResponses();
folders=    response.folderList;

    for(int i=0;i<folders.size();i++)
            {
                Log.e("Contents of folders are ",folders.get(i).getName());

            }
```

Im able to print BaseFolder.But how to access the inner tags and how can i get them in a list so that i can show them in some list view.Does any one have any idea?

Comment: i think your folder object needs a folder list field

Comment: Thank you. That was the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the Folder object to

```
@Root
public class Folder extends BaseResponse {




    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @ElementList(entry="folder", inline=true,name="name",required=false)
    public ArrayList<Folder> llfolder;





    public ArrayList<Folder> getLlfolder() {
        return llfolder;
    }

    public void setLlfolder(ArrayList<Folder> llfolder) {
        this.llfolder = llfolder;
    }

    @Attribute(required=false)
    private String id;

    @Attribute(required=false)
    private String name;



    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }



}
```